# VC++ - Including header from a DLL outside of solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio for C++ 2017, and I am trying to make a DLL for my own console application. I have the DLL and the console application in a different solution, so I am trying to link it.

Console project Path:
/Console Application/Console Application/Console Application.vcxproj

DLL path:
/Console Application/Console Application/DLL_test.dll

Lib path:
/Console Application/Console Application/DLL_test.lib

DLL contains:

- framework.h
- test.h
- test.cpp
- pch.h
- pch.cpp
- dllmain.cpp

In test.h:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int func();
```

In test.cpp:

```cpp
int func()
{
    return 5;
}
```

I have already added "../Console Application" in Additional Library Directories(Linker), Include Directories(VC++ directories) and Library Directories(VC++ directories), and added "DLL_test.lib" to Input(Linker). It compiles correctly, however, I can't include any of the headers in the DLL, when I should be able to include test.h.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "headers in the DLL"? Headers are separate files with `.h` extension - do you have any of those? You need them in order to use the DLL.

Comment: easy way is to copy `.h` and `.lib` to dir with `.cpp` files and `.dll` to folder with `.exe` And then use `#pragma comment(lib,"something")`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik question has been updated with a header file example

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин but can't the ```.dll``` be used just with the ```.lib```?

Comment: DLLs do not **contain** headers. The source for a DLL might have used headers, but this isn't .NET -- you need the header files as well as the DLL for the declarations that are in it.

Comment: The calling code needs to see a declaration `int func();`, one way or another; otherwise, the compiler has no idea what the name `func` means. Typically, the author of the DLL also supplies the header file that the consumer of the DLL could `#include`; just as they supply the .lib file that the consumer of the DLL could link with.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So if someone needs my DLL he would need the ```.lib```,```.dll``` and the ```.h```?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's usually done.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could you make an answer along with a tiny example of the ```.h```? Thanks for all your help.